# Error 'WORKDIR does not exist' when trying to install PHP8.0 in new Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Content of ***docker-composer.yml***:

```
    version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: laravel_docker
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  php-apache:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
        - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel_docker
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - database
```

subdirectory ./php contains this ***Dockerfile***:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt update \
        && apt install -y \
            g++ \
            libicu-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libzip-dev \
            zip \
            zlib1g-dev \
        && docker-php-ext-install \
            intl \
            opcache \
            pdo \
            pdo_pgsql \
            pgsql \

WORKDIR /var/www/laravel_docker

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

When trying to run "`docker-compose up -d --build`", I get the following error:

```
#0 12.75 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u3) ...
#0 15.05 error: /usr/src/php/ext/WORKDIR does not exist
#0 15.05
#0 15.05 usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] [--ini-name file.ini] ext-name [ext-name ...]
```

Why is the WROKDIR not being created by the installer?

I have created a folder "src" in the root of my project folder.

Comment: `pgsql \ ` implies the line continues but is in fact the last line of that command so it joins with `WORKDIR`. It basically tries to install an extension called `WORKDIR`. If you remove the trailing slash it should work

Comment: Perfect, that was it! Thanks! I just copied and pasted that code from a tutorial and did not expect any syntax errors...